# Join five table

Tags: mysql, join

I trying to create a filter output of images by joining five tables. I need the five tables joined because of my where statements. My sql is the following:

```
SELECT `files`.`id` AS `id`,
    `files`.`name` AS `name`,
    `files`.`size` AS `size`, 
    `files`.`type` AS `type`, 
    `files`.`url` AS `url`, 
    `files`.`title` AS `title`, 
    `files`.`description` AS `description`, 
    `files`.`category` AS `category` 
FROM `files` 
INNER JOIN `folders` 
    ON `files`.`category` = `folders`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `access` 
    ON `access`.`folder_id` = `folders`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `tags_files` 
    ON `tags_files`.`file_id` = `file`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `tags` 
    ON `tags`.`id` = `tags_files`.`tag_id` 
WHERE ( `access`.`user_id` = 11 ) 
    AND ( `files`.`type` = 'application/x-photoshop' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'image/jpeg' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' OR type = 'application/download' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' 
         OR type = 'application/msword' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'application/postscript' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'image/png' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'application/pdf' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'image/tiff' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'image/gif' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'application/octet-stream' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'application/zip' 
         OR `files`.`type` = 'text/plain' OR `files`.`type` = 'text/rtf' ) 
    AND ( `tags`.`name` = 'apple' )
```

I started off with with only three tables:

> files, folders, access

and everything went fine but by adding the last two

> tag, tags_files

I get the following error:

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'file.id' in 'on clause'

which is weird because thats the table I start off with ... Thanks for the help!

Comment: You start off with the table `files` with an s. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: thanks. I guess i was blind for a minute..

Answer (score 3):

there is no `file.id` in your request but `files.id` exist, i'm not sure cause i' dont have table structure. . .

Answer (score 0):

Your table name is incorrect. That is why you are getting that error. I think it must be files.id or use the appropriate table name with the column name

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, this query can be rewritten as follows - no performance benefit but I find it easier to read...

```
 SELECT f.id 
      , f.name 
      , f.size 
      , f.type 
      , f.url 
      , f.title 
      , f.description 
      , f.category 
   FROM files f
   JOIN folders d
     ON d.id = f.category
   JOIN access a
     ON a.folder_id = d.id 
   JOIN tags_files tf
     ON tf.file_id = f.id 
   JOIN tags t
     ON t.id = tf.tag_id 
  WHERE a.user_id = 11 
    AND f.type IN( 'application/x-photoshop'
                 , 'image/jpeg' 
                 , 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' 
                 , 'application/download' 
                 , 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' 
                 , 'application/msword' 
                 , 'application/postscript' 
                 , 'image/png' 
                 , 'application/pdf' 
                 , 'image/tiff'
                 , 'image/gif'
                 , 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation' 
                 , 'application/octet-stream'
                 , 'application/zip'
                 , 'text/plain' 
                 , 'text/rtf'
                 ) 
    AND t.name = 'apple';
```

Comment: Thanks! Question: if a image HAD to have multiple tags, how would you rewrite it than?

Comment: Go on. Take a guess - but all of IN, GROUP BY, HAVING and COUNT might be useful!